# Select time SQL whose has an interval of 10 minutes

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, intervals

[image]

I have a data table in my database containing these records, 
in my web page i have a DropDownList Containing the possible intervals (ex. per minute,per 5 minutes, per 10 minutes, per 30 minutes, per hour)

I want to select from these records according to the dropdown selected item, for example 10

> ```
> 7:00 
> 7:30
> 8:00
> 8:30
> 9:00
> 9:30
> 10:30
> ```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  And why when you chose 10 minutes, does it return records 30 minutes apart?

Comment: I am using MSSQL, yes it i need to get 10 20 30 40 50 60 if it is by 10 minutes and 1 2 3 4 ... if it is by 1 minute

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server, this will work:

```
Select Columns
From   YourTable
Where   DateDiff(Minute, 0, YourTimeColumn) % 10 = 0
```

Basically, the DateDiff function calculates the number of minutes that have elapsed since Jan 1, 1900 at midnight.  Then the modulus operator (the % symbol you see here) returns the remainder.  If that remainder is 0, then it is evenly divisible.  If you want 15 minute intervals, then replace the 10 with 15.  If you want hourly intervals, use 60 instead of 10.

For example, if your time was 1:30 am, the datediff function would return 90.  90 mod 10 = 0, therefore this row would be returned.

This assumes the data type of your column is datetime and not a string.

Comment: Slightly different approach, but nonetheless, same concept using the `modulus` operator: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c221/3