# Return rows depends on timestamp between them

Tags: sql, t-sql, row-number

The problem is that I want to get every n'th record from table but based on datetime.

I have table where I add record every 30 minutes with current state for each of my Sub objects, something like below:

| Id | SubId | Color | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7EB43D1D-7274-41C4-35DA-08D727A424E6 | orange | 2022-06-27 08:00:17.9843893 |
| 2 | A8FDBB08-3747-4B93-BC66-08D7382060CE | purple | 2022-06-27 08:00:17.9843893 |
| 3 | 7EB43D1D-7274-41C4-35DA-08D727A424E6 | red | 2022-06-27 08:30:15.7043893 |
| 4 | A8FDBB08-3747-4B93-BC66-08D7382060CE | blue | 2022-06-27 08:30:15.7043893 |
| 5 | 7EB43D1D-7274-41C4-35DA-08D727A424E6 | yellow | 2022-06-27 09:00:18.2841893 |
| 6 | A8FDBB08-3747-4B93-BC66-08D7382060CE | orange | 2022-06-27 09:00:18.2841893 |

And now I need to get points for one Sub object in certain period. But I dont want to get all entires cause I can end with too many points, I just want to get sometimes 1 per hour or 1 per day (it may change)

I already tried with **ROW_NUMBER** as I know that I'm adding point every 30 minutes but cause I need add where clausure for SubId then I might end with incorrect result (cause I'm adding or removing those Subobject in meanwhile)

```
    SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT [Id]
      ,[SubId]
      ,[Color]
      ,[Timestamp]
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OccupancyHistoryId) as rownum
    FROM [dbo].[Table]) AS t
 WHERE t.SubId = '7EB43D1D-7274-41C4-35DA-08D727A424E6' AND t.rownum % 2 = 0
```

Am I miss something obviouse? Or maybe my approach is wrong?

**Expected result**: For e.g records from **2022-06-27** to **2022-06-28** but only 1 per each 2 hours.

| Id | SubId | Color | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7EB43D1D-7274-41C4-35DA-08D727A424E6 | orange | 2022-06-27 08:00:17.9843893 |
| 5 | 7EB43D1D-7274-41C4-35DA-08D727A424E6 | yellow | 2022-06-27 10:00:18.2841893 |
| 10 | 7EB43D1D-7274-41C4-35DA-08D727A424E6 | orange | 2022-06-27 12:00:11.2821893 |

Comment: To help us understand your requirement, please show your desired resultset from the sample data. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Why not just limit by the timestamp in the WHERE clause and then use DATEPART to get the even hours?

Comment: @ourmandave yes it may work, but problem is that I migh want to have 1 entry per 2, 4, 6, 10 hours. Then it wont work

Comment: @KarolChudzik You're right, that won't work. In your sql above, what's OccupancyHistoryId?

Comment: What `DBMS` you are using?

Comment: Don't know if you found a solution yet, but it looks like [DATEDIFF is what you're after.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27285803/3585500)

Comment: @ourmandave OccupancyHistortyId was just a PK of table, forgot to rename it ;) and you are right. DateDiff seems to work fine. Even if I was thing about it before I didnt try to use it in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ourmandave's comments, I was able to resolve the problem. I didn't notice that I can use `DATEDIFF` with `%`.

So, to get entries only one per two hours, I simply write the query like that. So, obviously:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [dbo].[Table] WHERE DateDiff(Minute, 0, TimestampUtc) % 120 = 0
```